# File() don't work on Web-Host

Tags: php, file, xampp

From googling, I make a piece of code to full fill my needs.

This code just replace 'https' to 'http' from 'mylist.txt' on my Local Computer and display it on web browser.

But I wonder why this code is working well on XAMPP, but when I put in to web-host this code wont work.

is something that i missed ? or there need some setting in my web-host to make this code work?

```
$names=file('C:\\list\\mylist.txt');
foreach($names as $name)
{
   echo $name= str_replace("https","http","$name");
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web host could be running Unix based OS and the file path you have is windows based. Try for example putting the file in the same directory as your PHP and try with

```
$names=file('mylist.txt');
```

If it is that, use proper path for target host and that's it.

Comment: 'mylist.txt' is saved on my Local Computer is on C:\list\mylist.txt

Comment: @esi0411 You can't read files on your local computer in a script running on the server. You need to upload the file to the server.

Comment: @Hankly Yes,I thought that's right, but when i found "$names=file('C:\\list\\mylist.txt');" and implemented on XAMPP it run well, so I thought it should be running well on web-server too. Thank for your Confirmation, it should be uploaded to server first.

Answer (score 0):

Because on your web-host the path to your file won't be `'C:\\list\\mylist.txt'`. You should work with a relative path

Comment: 'mylist.txt' on my Local Computer is on C:\list\mylist.txt